# What company produced and owns The Lorax?

Tags: disney, producer, the-lorax

I've been looking around the internet and I've come across a very confusing dilemma. Did Walt Disney Productions produce The Lorax, or did Universal? (By way of Illumination Entertainment)

> The Lorax (also known as Dr. Seuss' The Lorax) is a 2012 American 3D computer-animated musical fantasy comedy film produced by Illumination Entertainment[...]

(Wikipedia)

> The Lorax is a 2016 American 3D computer animated science-fiction musical comedy adventure film created and produced at Walt Disney Animation Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures.

(Disney Fandom Website)

[image: Illumination Entertainment]
[image: Walt Disney Productions]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "Disney Fandom Website" you're referring to? The only such website I can find is [this one](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/The_Disney_Wiki), and it contains [no such article](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Special:Search?query=lorax&scope=internal&navigationSearch=true).

Comment: @F1Krazy - Google can find it from the quote, even if their own site can't find its own errmm.. fundament… with both hands & a map ;))

Comment: Discrepancy fanon/fandom discovered & added to answer. It's from a decidedly non-authoritative source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Disney ***Fanon*** Fandom site](https://the-disney-fanon.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lorax) seems to be rather at odds with other authorities. (As it's a fan wiki, I doubt it's subject to quite the stringent fact-checking that Wikipedia and IMDB are). They've also got the date wrong, it's 2012 not 2016.

*from comments* it would seem that "fanon" means it's some kind of made up wish-list, who-cares-whether-it's-true non-canon structure… Avoid.

Both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lorax_(film)) & [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1482459/companycredits?ref_=tt_dt_co) consider it it entirely [Universal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Pictures) - [Illumination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illumination_(company)) is a part of Universal.
IMDB mentions Disney as a distributor in 2019/20 but in no other capacity.

From WIkipedia -

> The Lorax (also known as Dr. Seuss' The Lorax) is a 2012 American 3D computer-animated musical fantasy comedy film produced by Illumination Entertainment and based on Dr. Seuss' children's book of the same name. The film was released by Universal Pictures on March 2, 2012, on what would have been Seuss's 108th birthday.

I can find no other claim to it being either Disney or 2016.
Let's assume it was written by some over-eager, under-fact-checked fan. Fake news ;)

Comment: Upon closer inspection, that's the "Disney Fanon Wiki". "Fanon" literally means "alternative canon that fans made up". In other words, the site isn't *supposed* to be accurate, and one shouldn't believe anything they read on it.

Comment: I had just this moment noticed that too - it's some ripoff site. It seems to be the only source of that image with 'disney' on it too.

Comment: Why would they post "facts" if they're not meant to be accurate? This is another thing that confuses me.